# Dynamically adding active class to a tag to all parent menu till top level dynamically built nav menu link item using JavaSCript

Tags: javascript

I would like to dynamically add an 'active' class to the navigation menu and its all parent till top level menu links when it is clicked using addEventListener. The nav menu is has also been added dynamically from database using php. I need to add an 'active' class to the navigation menu do this with only JavaScript. Thank you for any help.

Here is what I have so far. its working for up to 3 level of drop-down but i need for loop are while loop till id="home_li"

```
HTML CODE

<nav id="nav-bar" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark bg-gradient px-lg-3 py-lg-2 fixed-top d-print-none">
<div class="container-fluid align-items-center">
    <div class=" col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-auto text-end">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main_nav"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_nav">
    <!--Home Nav-->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ms-3" id="main_ul">
        <li id="home_li" class="me-4"><a
                class="nav-link active btn btn-dark bg-gradient border border-1 border-white"
                href="http://index.php" id="active">Home</a></li>
        <li id="home_li" class="nav-item dropdown me-4"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside">Admin</a></li>
        <li id="home_li" class="nav-item dropdown me-4"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown
                Section-1</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                <li class="dropend"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                        data-bs-auto-close="outside">Dropdown
                        Section-1-1</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://Page-1-1-1.php">Page-1-1-1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://Page-1-1-2.php">Page-1-1-2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://Page-1-1-3.php">Page-1-1-3</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://Page-1-1-4.php">Page-1-1-4</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://Page-1-1-5.php">Page-1-1-5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropend"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                        data-bs-auto-close="outside">Dropdown
                        Section-1-2</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://Page-1-2-1.php">Page-1-2-1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://Page-1-2-2.php">Page-1-2-2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://Page-1-2-3.php">Page-1-2-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropend"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                        data-bs-auto-close="outside">Dropdown
                        Section-1-3</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu shadow">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://Page-1-3-1.php">Page-1-3-1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://Page-1-3-2.php">Page-1-3-2</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://Page-1-3-3.php">Page-1-3-3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://Page-1-1.php">Page-1-1</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://Page-1-2.php">Page-1-2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="home_li" class="nav-item dropdown me-4"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside">Dropdown
                Section-2</a></li>
        <li id="home_li" class="nav-item dropdown me-4"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-auto-close="outside">Dropdown
                Section-3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var activePage = window.location.pathname;
var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('nav ul li a').forEach(link => {
    if (link.href.includes(`${activePage}`)) {
        link.id = 'active';
        var a = document.getElementById('active');
        var p = a.parentElement;
        var p1Id = p.getAttribute('id');

        if (p1Id == 'home_li') {
            link.classList.add('active', 'btn', 'btn-dark', 'bg-gradient', 'border', 'border-1',
                'border-white');
        } else if (p1Id != 'home_li') {
            var p1 = p.parentElement;
            var p2 = p1.parentElement;
            var p2Id = p2.getAttribute('id');

            if (p2Id == 'home_li') {
                link.classList.add('active');
                var p2child = p2.children;
                p2child[0].classList.add('active');
                p2child[0].classList.add('btn', 'btn-dark', 'bg-gradient', 'border', 'border-1',
                    'border-white');
            } else if (p2Id != 'home_li') {
                var p3 = p2.parentElement;
                var p4 = p3.parentElement;
                var p4Id = p4.getAttribute('id');

                if (p4Id == 'home_li') {
                    link.classList.add('active');
                    var p2child = p2.children;
                    var p3child = p4.children;
                    p2child[0].classList.add('active');
                    p3child[0].classList.add('active');
                    p3child[0].classList.add('btn', 'btn-dark', 'bg-gradient', 'border', 'border-1',
                        'border-white');
                } else if (p4Id != 'home_li') {
                    var p5 = p4.parentElement;
                    var p6 = p5.parentElement;
                    var p6Id = p6.getAttribute('id');

                    if (p6Id == 'home_li') {
                        link.classList.add('active');
                        var p2child = p2.children;
                        var p3child = p4.children;
                        var p4child = p6.children;
                        p2child[0].classList.add('active');
                        p3child[0].classList.add('active');
                        p4child[0].classList.add('active');
                        p4child[0].classList.add('btn', 'btn-dark', 'bg-gradient', 'border', 'border-1',
                            'border-white');
                    } else if (p6Id != 'home_li') {
                        var p7 = p6.parentElement;
                        var p8 = p7.parentElement;
                        var p8Id = p8.getAttribute('id');

                        if (p8Id == 'home_li') {
                            link.classList.add('active');
                            var p2child = p2.children;
                            var p3child = p4.children;
                            var p4child = p6.children;
                            var p5child = p8.children;
                            p2child[0].classList.add('active');
                            p3child[0].classList.add('active');
                            p4child[0].classList.add('active');
                            p5child[0].classList.add('active');
                            p5child[0].classList.add('btn', 'btn-dark', 'bg-gradient', 'border', 'border-1',
                                'border-white');
                        } else {
                            link.classList.add('active');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Your original HTML has some issues. The id attribute must be unique. Also, in your opening `nav` tag, there's no space between the closing of the quotes for the id attribute and the beginning of the class attribute. As for the JS part, perhaps a better solution would be to target the parent, like you would normally do in jQuery - `$(elem).on(event,child,function(){...});`. A vanilla JS version of the `.on()` event handler can be found [here](https://gomakethings.com/a-vanilla-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-on-method/).

Comment: hi thank you for your reply. Yes i notice that there is no space in nav tag between class and id in my code there is a space the mistake was happen when i copy and paste the code

Comment: hi thank you for your reply. Yes i notice that there is no space in nav tag between class and id in my code there is a space the mistake was happen when i copy and paste the code. Yes your right the id must be unique i will change id home_li to class home_li. can you give solution for this. i need if we click any menu need to add active class for clicked menu and select all parent li till top li add active class to next child of li. my code working for 3 level dropdown menus but i need n number